# How to convert String to UTF-8 to Integer in Swift

Tags: swift, utf-8, integer, character

I'm trying to take each character (individual number, letter, or symbol) from a string file name without the extension and put each one into an array index as an integer of the utf-8 code (i.e. if the file name is "A1" without the extension, I would want "A" as an int "41" in first index, and "1" as int "31" in second index)

Here is the code I have but I'm getting this error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'", my guess is because .utf8 still keeps it as a string type:

```
for i in allNoteFiles {
        var CharacterArray : [Int] = []
        
        for character in i {
            var utf8Character = String(character).utf8 
            CharacterArray.append(utf8Character)    //error is here
        }
....`//more code down here within the for in loop using CharacterArray indexes`
```

I'm sure the answer is probably simple, but I'm very new to Swift.

I've tried appending var number instead with:

```
var number = Int(utf8Character)
```

and

```
var number = (utf8Character).IntegerValue
```

but I get errors "No exact matches in call to initializer" and "Value of type 'String.UTF8View' has no member 'IntegerValue'"

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason

```swift
var utf8Character = String(character).utf8 
CharacterArray.append(utf8Character)
```

doesn't work for you is because `utf8Character` is not a single integer, but a [`UTF8View`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/utf8view): a lightweight way to iterate over the UTF-8 codepoints in a string. Every `Character` in a `String` can be made up of *any number* of UTF-8 bytes (individual integers) — while ASCII characters like `"A"` and `"1"` map to a single UTF-8 byte, the vast majority of characters do not: every UTF-8 code point maps to between 1 and *4* individual bytes. The [Encoding section of UTF-8 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) has a few very illustrative examples of how this works.

Now, assuming that you *do* want to split a string into individual UTF-8 bytes (either because you can *guarantee* your original string is ASCII-only, so the assumption that "character = byte" holds, or because you actually care about the bytes [though this is *rarely* the case]), there's a short and idiomatic solution to what you're looking for.

`String.UTF8View` is a [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) of `UInt8` values (individual bytes), and as such, you can use the [`Array` initializer which takes a `Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/init(_:)-1ip9h):

```swift
let characterArray: [UInt8] = Array(i.utf8)
```

If you need an array of `Int` values instead of `UInt8`, you can map the individual bytes ahead of time:

```swift
let characterArray: [Int] = Array(i.utf8.lazy.map { Int($0) })
```

(The `.lazy` avoids creating and storing an array of values in the middle of the operation.)

However, do note that if you aren't careful (e.g., your original string is *not* ASCII), you're bound to get very unexpected results from this operation, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting the array of UInt8 into an array of Ints. When I use your code, I get an error saying it requires the type 'UInt8' and 'Int' to be equivalent. I get rid of that error when I change [UInt8] to [Int], but then I can't append the UTF8 character to the array.

Comment: @TrappinNachos Apologies — the second example had a typo, which I've fixed. Two questions: (1) is there a reason you're using the second snippet (`Int`) instead of sticking with the first (`UInt8`)? (2) If you do need the `Int` version, you will only be able to append `Int` values to the array; are you converting your appended character to `Int` before appending?

Comment: Nevermind all good, I realized that I am able to do everything that I need to do using just UInt8, it just takes a few more steps because they can't become negative numbers. Thank you for the help!